# I'm trying to create a hierarchical state machine, but don't understand how to transition to a superstate

Tags: unity, statemachine

I have a `CharacterController` that implements a `StateMachine` that uses a number of states and transitions. The `StateMachine` checks for a valid transition to a new state at the start of every frame, and either moves to a new state or continues ticking the current state. Here is a brief example of all of this working together:

```
public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public StateMachine { get; private set; } 
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        InitializeStateMachine();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        StateMachine.Tick(); // Checks for valid transitions, and then sets and/or ticks the appropriate state
    }

    private void InitializeStateMachine()
    {
        StateMachine = new StateMachine();

        // Create states
        var idleState = new IdleState(this);
        var walkState = new WalkState(this);
        var jumpState = new JumpState(this);

        // Add some transitions
        Func<bool> idleToWalk() => () => IsGrounded && velocity.x != 0;
        Func<bool> idleToJump() => () => IsGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.Space);

                                   // From       To       Condition
        StateMachine.AddTransition(idleState, walkState, idleToWalk());
        StateMachine.AddTransition(idleState, jumpState, idleToJump());
    }
}
```

I really like this implementation because the states and the `StateMachine` are decoupled; only the "motor" class knows about both of these things, which makes it very easy for me to keep my code clean. Specifically, I like that the individual states don't have state-switching code in them; then, if I want to make changes to how transitions between certain states occur, I have all of that code in one place (the `InitializeStateMachine` method, or I can add transitions in specific places later).

However, as my project grows I'm running into an issue where I'm having to create many transitions to states that share similar functionality. For example, the `idle` and `walk` states only work if my controller is grounded, so if I have a `fall` state then I need to make transitions from the `fall` state to every possible grounded state:

```
Func<bool> fallToIdle() => () => IsGrounded && velocity.x == 0;
Func<bool> fallToWalk() => () => IsGrounded && velocity.x != 0;
Func<bool> fallToSlide() => () => IsGrounded && velocity.x != 0 && Input.GetButtonDown("Slide");
```

It would be nicer if I could simply transition to some kind of generic `GroundedState` that handles the next steps as needed.

I read that one way to help solve this problem is to create a `hierarchical state machine`, but, though the concept makes sense to me, I don't understand how to implement it in the context of my current system.

I assume that I would need to make a `GroundedState` parent class from which any ground states inherit, but how do I actually make transitions from `fall` to `grounded`, and then get from `grounded` to, for example, `walk` or `slide` in a single frame? Would the `GroundedState` need a reference to the `StateMachine` class so that it can set the correct substate accordingly?

Comment: "It would be nicer if I could simply transition to some kind of generic GroundedState that handles the next steps as needed." — Well, why not do literally that? An intermediate state that instantly transitions elsewhere.